# Show div if it is display style none & hide if display style is block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set a div's style to block if its display style is none, and set it to none if its style is block. I wrote this code, but it is not working. What to do?

```
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #menu {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        z-index: 100;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: url(images/menu.jpg) center no-repeat;
        margin: auto;
    }

    #line {
        margin-top: 19px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 5%;
        z-index: -1;
        width: 90%;
    }

    #menu_element {
        height: 240px;
        background: #06C;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    @keyframes menu_animate {
        from {
            height: 0px;
        }
        to {
            height: 240px;
        }
    }

    @keyframes menu_animate_reverse {
        from {
            height: 240px;
        }
        to {
            height: 0px;
        }
    }
</style>

<script>
    function menuShow() {
        if (document.getElementById("menu_element").style.display == "none") {
            document.getElementById("menu_element").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("menu_element").style.animationName = "menu_animate";
            document.getElementById("menu_element").style.animationDuration = "1s";
        }
        if (document.getElementById("menu_element").style.display == "block") {
            document.getElementById("menu_element").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("menu_element").style.animationName = "menu_animate_reverse";
            document.getElementById("menu_element").style.animationDuration = "1s";
        }
    }
</script>`

<div id="menu" onClick="menuShow();"></div>
<div id="menu_element"></div>
```

What is wrong with my code? So after clicking id menu, if id 'menu_element' is visible it needs to hide and if it is hidden then it has to be shown.

Comment: can u kindly add ur code in a jsfiddle or codepen. with the issue?.

Comment: Use `else if` for the second `if` block. As it currently is your first `if` will end up setting the element style to `block` and the second `if` will end up always being true as it was just set to be `block`

Answer (score 6):

You can remove the onclick altogether if you have more than one #menu elements. Using JQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(#menu).click(menuShow());
}

function menuShow() {
    if ($(this).css('display')=='block') {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    } else if ($(this).css('display')==('none') {
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

If you had more display cases you wanted to address, a switch statement might be the better choice.

Comment: `$(#menu)`, think you meant `$('#menu')`. _"if you have more than one #menu elements"_ even if they did ids have to be unique, id selectors will only ever return 1 element. Also you are executing `menuShow` immediately instead of passing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>function menuShow(){
debugger
  var curr=document.getElementById("menu_element");
    if(curr.style.display == "none"){
    document.getElementById("menu_element").style.display ="block";
    document.getElementById("menu_element").style.animationName ="menu_animate";
    document.getElementById("menu_element").style.animationDuration = "1s";
    }
    else if(curr.style.display == "block"){
    document.getElementById("menu_element").style.display ="none";
    document.getElementById("menu_element").style.animationName ="menu_animate_reverse";
    document.getElementById("menu_element").style.animationDuration = "1s";
    }
    }
        </script>

</head>
<body>   
 <div id="menu" onClick="menuShow();">
Click me to hide
</div>
<div id="menu_element" style="background-color:red;display:block;" >
I Love this code.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("menu_element").style.display` can be `none` or just empty string `""` :
check the jsfiddle here :

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwzkdLww/)

Answer (score 0):

try below mentioned sample.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Menu Show or Hide by java script</title>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function showOrHide(){
               var melement = document.getElementById('menu_element');
               
               if(melement.style.display == 'none'){
                   melement.style.display = 'block';
               }
               else{
                   melement.style.display = 'none';
               }
           }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu" onclick="showOrHide();" style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid red;">
        </div>
        <div id="menu_element" style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid red;">
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function menuShow(){
    if(document.getElementById("menu_element").css('display') == "none"){
      document.getElementById("menu_element").css("background-color", "block");
      document.getElementById("menu_element").css("animationName", "menu_animate");
      document.getElementById("menu_element").css("animationDuration", "1s");
    }
    if(document.getElementById("menu_element").css('display') == "block"){
      document.getElementById("menu_element").css("background-color", "none");
      document.getElementById("menu_element").css("animationName", "menu_animate_reverse");
      document.getElementById("menu_element").css("animationDuration", "1s");
    }
    }
```

Comment: var curr=document.getElementById("#menu_element"); always null.please check your code

Comment: you can just add && !=null,

Comment: woops my appoligies you dont need #before menu_element

Comment: `document.getElementById("menu_element").css`??? getElementById is a DOM method, and returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object